# getCurrentPosition always callback error on my computer

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

So, i have a site with a geoloc system.

This system works well for my friends, but when i test on my PC, i always have the error callback.

This is my code :

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 30000,
            maximumAge: 100
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(localizeMe, errorLocalize, options);
    } else {
        bootbox.alert("Impossible de trouver votre position.", function(response) {
            if(response)
                $(this).delay(200).fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();
        });
    }
```

So, for my friends, the callback `localizeMe` is always call, so the script works.

But with me, i always have the callback `errorLocalize`..

I test on FF, Chrome, and safari on my Ipad, but error, error and error... I'am on windows 7 64 bits.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Can you log `err.code` and tell us what the error code is?

Comment: Do you have location tracking enabled?

Comment: don't have any error...

Comment: location tracking ? On a computer ?